# how do i add html page in my iphone xcode project?

Tags: iphone, html, xcode

can anyone tell how to add html in my iphone project??
And their is no html option which i click on add new file in class group...why is that???

Comment: You should accept some answers on your other questions

Comment: Hi, I too wanna know how can I accept the answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

simply create a blank file and rename it to html or add existing html file to the project.
the next step depends on how you wish to use the html file.

Say if you want to load a local file called page.html, first you add the file to project,and in the build phases of your project, and the page.html to `Copy Bundle Resources`, and run this in your app, it writes the file to the `documents` dictionary of your app/

```
NSString *Html = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"page" ofType:@"html"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
[Html writeToFile:[[self docPath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"page.html"] atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
[Html release];
```

and your webview should call this to load the file:

```
NSArray *docPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docPath = [docPaths objectAtIndex:0];
[myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"page.html"]]]];
```

and it's done.

Comment: hi, i want to know how to use the html???i mean to show content of html file in the iphone simulator.thank you

Comment: You want to load a local html file into a UIWebView? See my updates

Answer (score 0):

What you might be looking for is documentation and example code for the UIWebView class of UIKit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UIWebView` to show your html file like this

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLString]];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

where `URLString` contains is your file url.