# Add JSON file to app

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to add a JSON file to my app and read from this file at runtime. I have looked online for how to do this, but most of the information is concerned with reading the file. I cannot find any information online about how to make the file available at runtime. Most of the stuff online seems to be reading from a bundle, but I have no idea how to create a bundle or how to add a JSON file to it. Can someone provide some information?

Comment: Drag and drop your JSON file into your Supporting Files folder.

Comment: Please check for answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201997/how-do-i-add-html-page-in-my-iphone-xcode-project

Answer (score 3):

This is a fairly simple task. This is how you would do it:

1. Create a new folder in finder. Name it MyProject. You can name it anything.
2. Drag and drop you .JSON file into it.
3. Rename the folder to MyProject.bundle. You shall see below alert.
4. Click on "Add" button.
5. Finally, drag and drop this to your Xcode project and use it. From your description, I believe, you already know how to read .JSON from it.

[image]

**PS: Although, as Gurtej suggested, you can directly add your .JSON into project an read it from there. My post answers your query as how we create a bundle and add files to it.**

Comment: Why would you do all of this simply to add a JSON file to an existing project?

Comment: @rmaddy I know but one of the question OP asked was "how to create a bundle or how to add a JSON file to it".

Comment: That's because the OP doesn't know what a bundle is. There's no need to create one. Just add the JSON file to the app's existing resources.

Comment: I agree. I shall remove this post once OP respond on Gurtej comments.